# How to set limit and offset on multiple Mysql server?

Tags: java, mysql

I have a students page I want to add a simple pagination but problem is student information comes from different mysql servers. What is the best way add a pagination to this page?

```
RequestMapping(value = "loadStudents.json", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String loadStudents(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
   int offset = ...
   int limit = ....

   for(Server server : mysqlServers){  //I got 3 server here
      studentService.getStudents(server, offset, limit);
   }
}
```

**EDIT:**  ALL students tables on different servers have same table schema;

```
[id, name, surname, information, address]
```

Currently I got 3 Mysql servers but I can have more. Server size is not under my control.

Display of student information is not important. I mean If I got 5 records per page;

```
student22(from server1)
student11(from server1)
student42(from server1)
student11(from server1)
student33(from server1)
```

OR

```
student1(from server1)
student22(from server2)
student334(from server3)
student44(from server1)
student444(from server3)
```

Comment: The problem of pagination on a single server doesn't have a _single_ right solution. Many things depend on the particularities of your data and of how you want to display it (since many of the issues stem more from UX). See this article on [Postgres pagination](https://getpocket.com/redirect?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.citusdata.com%2Fblog%2F2016%2F03%2F30%2Ffive-ways-to-paginate%2F&formCheck=c6f4865ffdcf1e165221e221555f47b3) for examples. You need to provide a little bit more info on (1) how the students table is structure and (2) how you want to display the info and (3) why there are 3 servers?